# Material IU icon with rectangle background

Tags: material-ui

I can't find any documentation on how to create an icon with rectangle backgrounds like here: [image: AddIcon]
There are no props for `<Icon />` or `<SvgIcon />` that I can find that would do this out of the box. I can style them like that myself, but was wondering if there is an existing way.

Comment: Did you manage to check the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useStyles` to add colors to your elements:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    "& > svg": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1)
    }
  },
  icon1: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius
  },
  icon2: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    color: theme.palette.text.primary,
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius
  },
  icon3: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.text.primary,
    color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius
  },
  icon4: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius
  }
}));
```

And inside your icon:

```
<div className={classes.root}>
  <AddIcon fontSize="large" color="primary" className={classes.icon1} />
  <AddIcon fontSize="large" color="primary" className={classes.icon2} />
  <AddIcon fontSize="large" color="primary" className={classes.icon3} />
  <AddIcon fontSize="large" color="primary" className={classes.icon4} />
</div>
```

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-icons-styling-8t4rb?file=/demo.js

Comment: I know I can style them myself. My confusion perhaps comes from the fact that usually they provide example code for their demos. Icons page shows very promising demos with no code that shows how they were achieved.